# Why DataGridColumn not getting removed from DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have custom `DataGridView` control and in that control there is `RefreshGrid()` method which fill `DataGridView` by using DataSource. Now I am tring to remove few columns from that `DataGridView` after DataSource binding but unable to remove those, those column not getting removed but add at the end of DataGridView, when I call `RefreshGrid()` method again then those column get removed from `DataGridView`. Here is code for method `RefreshGrid()`

```
    public void RefreshGrid()
    {
        DataTable _table = AccessConnectionManagers.GetDataTableBySQLQuery("select Colm1,Colm2,Colm3 from TableName");
        //Data Source Binding with DataGridView
        this.DataSource = _table;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty("Colm1"))
        {
            var _colmArray = GridRemoveColumnName.Split(new char[] { ',', ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Where(a => this.Columns.Contains(a)).Select(a => a).ToArray();

            foreach (string colm in _colmArray)
            {
                //Remove column after Source Binding
                this.Columns.Remove(colm);
            }
        }
    }
```

Call for `RefreshGrid()`

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myDataGridView1.RefreshGrid();
    }
```

Please find the error and suggest me the solution.

Comment: **Now I am tring to remove few columns from that DataGridView after DataSource binding** ??? Please show us the code where you are removing these columns after DataSource binding

Comment: The code works OK, you can always remove the datagridviewcolumns after binding.

Comment: @MicrosoftDN `this.Columns.Remove(colm);`

Comment: @KingKing Yes this work, but when I call `RefreshGrid()` second time

Comment: are you sure you call RefreshGrid() in first time.

Comment: @HabibZare Added code on I call `RefreshGrid()`

Comment: what is this :  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty("Colm1"))

Comment: @HabibZare :) actually I have some variable over there but for understanding I replace it(It is one of Custom Grid Property)

Comment: maybe this condition is false in first call but is true in second call

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35923/discussion-between-ankush-madankar-and-habib-zare)

Comment: By calling `RefreshGrid()` method on `FormLoad` event my problem get solve.. I dont know why its isnt working when I calling same method on form Contructor..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I found answer for this question
>
> I need to call RefreshGrid() method on Form Load not on Form
>   constructor, after calling it on Form Log my problem get solved. But I
>   dont know why it wasnt working on Form constructor.

I guess you try to access columns that do not exist yet. You are using the `DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns` functionnality and even if you set the `DataSource` property, The `DatagridView` won't create columns until the grid is displayed. It's why it doesn't work in form constructor, but works in `form_Load` event or after that the grid has been displayed.

Using `form_Load` is maybe a possible workaround, but I reommand you to use the [`DataGridView.DataBindingComplete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.databindingcomplete.aspx) event which is especially designed to handle this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You should retrieve only columns from data table that you want to display in DataGridView.

```
var results = _table
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Where("Add your condition")
    .Select("your columns names");

this.DataSource = results;
```

So now you don't need to remove any columns from DataGridView

Comment: This removes/filters out rows not columns?

Comment: @KingKing: from select statement in linq we only gets columns that we need. where cond can be remove. if not required

Comment: I overlooked the `Select`, however this still needs the `CopyToDataTable` if the OP wants his DataSource to be a `DataTable`. I guess we have to use `Anonymous type` here to select the columns, so `CopyToDataTable` can't be used.

Comment: @King King: Yes can do, If data table is required in Post Processing.

Comment: @PankajAgarwal Yes, this also work, but I want those columns in DataSource so that I can do updatation in database by using DataAdaptor

Answer (score 0):

I found answer for this question

I need to call RefreshGrid() method on Form Load not on Form constructor, after calling it on Form Load my problem get solved. But I dont know why it wasnt working on Form constructor.